# Blockchain Token Mint Error 'nonce too low: address 0x1...F current nonce (491) > tx nonce (490)

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm doing transactions with Contract on Avalanche test network. I am simply minting an NFT in my Contract. I'm implementing this in Node.js as an API. Normally my codes are working. However, sometimes I get an error like this and I couldn't figure out why. Can you help me?

```
message: {
    code: -32000,
    message: 'nonce too low: address 0x190cc0978615a474092676aB740F486b7f528A5F current nonce (491) > tx nonce (490) -- Reason given: Custom error (could not decode).',
    reason: 'Custom error (could not decode)'
  }
```

Here are the parts I made with Mint:

On Contracts...

```
function mint(address minter, string memory uri) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        idToOwner[newItemId] = minter;
        _safeMint(minter, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, uri);

        emit Mint(minter, uri, newItemId);
        return newItemId;
}
```

On Nodejs API...

```
const mintMetaData = async (_id, mintURL, res) => {
    const _instance = await hyliContract.at(process.env.CONTRACT_NFT_ADDRESS);

    try {
        const result = await _instance.mint(provider.getAddress(), mintURL, { from: provider.getAddress() });
...
```